# What's a clean way to construct Marionette views over pre-rendered HTML?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I keep running into this problem over and over and I don't always know how to address it. For example, I have a page loading from the server. That page has a list of entities (A collection of `Backbone.Marionette.ItemView`s inside of a `CollectionView` or `CompositeView`. How can I cleanly replace that pre-rendered HTML with Backbone/Marionette-managed objects without tearing down the initial HTML?

The problem is that I otherwise have to wait until the page is finished loading and then build the views off of data, creating a pause and then a flash before the page is finally, truly ready.

Comment: If I understand correctly you want bind the existing html to views? You're talking about replacing the pre-rendered html as well as not tearing down the initial html. Could you elaborate a little more?

If you don't mind updating the page, I'd just replace the contents of the list container with your collection or compositeView.

Comment: Either way, really. I just want to avoid that visual flash that accompanies building up and rendering the views after the page load. From reading through the Marionette source, it appears that some things only get set up on render, so I'm left hacking the library's internals if I want to put a Marionette view over existing HTML. If I can replace the HTML without that visual flash, then that seems rather straight-forward. Build the HTML server-side so the user can see it and then replace it in JS so that it actually does something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do it this way:
- Load a pre-rendered list which is in a container with id: #container
- Create a marionette region on that id #container
- Show the 'marionnette-ized' view in that container

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Cardiff/D6hXZ/

Notice that the html is updated after 5 seconds with the marionette version:

```
// Create a region
var rm = new Marionette.RegionManager();
rm.addRegion("container", "#container");

// Show the collectionView with a delay, replacing the pre-rendered html
_.delay(function() {
    console.log('updating list with marionette views!');
    rm.get('container').show(movieCompViewInstance);
}, 5000);
```

You don't see any flashing, just a change of text color to indicate the marionette version is active. Also before clicking the delete button won't do anything, after it's loaded, they'll work.

Comment: OK, so literally just build a new view when ready and immediately render it over top of the old HTML. Looks like there's no down-side. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, and technically it replaces the old HTML instead of being put 'on top' of it. You're welcome!